# Why is the result (accuracy) of evaluate_generator different from the result (accuracy) of predict_generator in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, multilabel-classification

I created a model for image classification, followed by learning and evaluation using `Keras`.

There was a problem during the accuracy assessment using the learned model.

There are a total of 12 classes, from 1 to 11, plus an X class.
`1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, X`

I carried out the accuracy evaluation using two functions `evaluate_generator` and `predict_generator`.

Using the output of `predict_generator`, the class with the highest probability for each image is designated as the predict class.

So I evaluated the accuracy according to whether the actual class and the predicted class are the same.

```py
label_count = []
for label in labels:
    if label != '1' :
        test_id = test_id+[os.path.basename(fl) for fl in glob('{}/{}/*png'.format(test_path, label))]
        if label == 'X' :
            label_count+= ['12' for _ in glob('{}/{}/*png'.format(test_path, label))]
        else :
            label_count+= [label for _ in glob('{}/{}/*png'.format(test_path, label))]
    else :
        test_id = [os.path.basename(fl) for fl in glob('{}/{}/*png'.format(test_path, label))]
        label_count+= [label for _ in glob('{}/{}/*png'.format(test_path, label))]
```

```py
preds = model.evaluate_generator(
        test_generator,
        steps=len(test_id))
print("%s: %.2f%%" %(model.metrics_names[1], preds[1]*100))
```

```py
preds = model.predict_generator(
        test_generator,
        steps=len(test_id),
        verbose=1)
preds_list = list(preds)
temp=0
loss_count = 0
for pred in preds_list :
    results = 0
    top_ = 0
    for i,pr in enumerate(pred) :
        results += float(pr)*(i+1)
        if float(pr) > top_ :
            top_ = float(pr)
            top = i+1
    predict_ = round(results,2)
    true_ = int(label_count[temp])
    loss_ = abs(round(true_ - round(results,2),2))
    if abs(top-true_) <= 1 :
        loss_count += 1
    # print('True class : ',true_,' Predict class : ',top,' Predict linear : ',predict_, ' loss : ', loss_)
    temp += 1
print ('accuracy : ', round(loss_count/len(test_id)*100,2), '%')
```

`evaluate_generator` output is `acc: 90.54%`

but `predict_generator` output is `accuracy : 56.76%`